# How to use page metadata while using wp_list_pages()?

Tags: custom-field, menus, pages, wp-list-pages

I'm creating my pages links in wordpress, using `wp_list_pages()`. each link contains an `<i>` tag which displays retina icons. I want to set a different class for each link in order to display a different retina icon. my code so far is this:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('link_before=<i class="A RETINA ICON CLASS NAME"></i>&link_after=<br >'); ?>
```

How can I do that using pages meta data?or other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with jQuery by using *.eq()* to add a specific class to each *i* element.

Example:

Add a class to your *i* element from PHP.

```
<?php wp_list_pages('link_before=<i class="retina_icon"></i>&link_after=<br >'); ?>
```

Then add another class to it with jQuery.

```
jQuery('.retina-icon:eq(0)').addClass("retina-icon-1");
jQuery('retina-icon:eq(1)').addClass("retina-icon-2");
```